# The compilation of Miracl for the DSP C6713 of Texas Instruments

Tags: code-composer

I was trying to compile the Miracl library by using Code Composer Studio V3.1. The target DSP is a C6713 made by texas instruments. I also added to the project the files: csl6713.lib, dsk6713bsl.lib,rts6700.lib and c6713dsk.cmd. The file in C is config.c. The project compiles and runs without problem but the obtained file miracl.lst is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of MIRACL contains a file texasdsp.txt which has specific advice on building the library for the C6713 DSP, using Code Composer Studio V5. Download from www.certivox.com